# How to display blade.php files using firebase

Tags: laravel-5, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am new to firebase. When I am trying to display the hosted blade.php files through firebase that files will be directly get downloaded. But I need to display them as web pages. So how can I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase Hosting is for serving static assets only. It will not interpret your PHP code/Blade template and will instead serve them uninterpreted.

If you want to serve PHP, you will need to find a PHP hosting service.

If you want to use Firebase Hosting, you'll have to serve static HTML, such as for a [single-page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).