# Using Firebase with a PHP script

Tags: php, firebase

I've always written my web services from scratch (PHP + MySQL). Firebase has caught my attention for its apparent ease of use and speed of development. Before I started integrating it into my app, I had already written some PHP scripts which query a public API and return the results to my app. I'm thinking it would be cool if I could use Firebase to cache these results by adding them to the NoSQL DB, but I'm not totally clear on how I would do this. Can I host my scripts somewhere in Firebase? If not, I guess I just grab one of the open source SDKs off Github, but it seems like hosting scripts outside of the service isn't the ideal workflow. Maybe there is a way to call an external API and parse the results with Firebase itself?

Comment: Firebase Hosting cannot run your PHP code. Since I just answered a question about that, I'll link you there instead of repeating it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39522840/how-to-display-blade-php-files-using-firebase

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display blade.php files using firebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39522840/how-to-display-blade-php-files-using-firebase)

Answer (score 2):

From Firebase website

> We deliver all of your **static content (html, js, images, etc.)** over a secure SSL connection and serve it on a CDN.

Firebase Hosting is for hosting static assets

[Answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35524033)

Answer (score 1):

No, Firebase can't run your code, but what you have in mind is a perfectly legitimate workflow. You can move the bulk of your non-sensitive business logic to the front end, while running some secret sauce on a server.

The way to think of it is that your server is just another client to Firebase, it just has extra privileges and duties.

[Read this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/03/where-does-firebase-fit-in-your-app.html). Your use case sounds like **Pattern 2: Firebase-powered app with server code**, which they partly explain as:

> In some cases it’s not possible to get away with only client code. Let’s look at a few examples:
>
> - You want your app to integrate with third party APIs (like Twilio to send an SMS, or SendGrid to send an email).