# firebase hosting not redirecting

Tags: php, html, firebase-hosting

I have made a simple site and I am using firebase hosting to make it live. My index page send information to php file for processing. The website is working perfectly on localhost but when I deployed it on firebase, the php instead of redirect to next page it download the php code file. I have attached my php page code kindly help me to solve the issue

```
<?php
$user=$_POST["username"];
$pass=$_POST["password"];

if($user=="admin" and $pass=="admin")
{
    echo '<script>alert("Welcome admin")</script>'; 
    header( "refresh:1;url=data.html" );
}

else{
    echo '<script>alert("Wrong Credentials !")</script>'; 
    header( "refresh:1;url=index.html" );
   
    die();
}
?>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly. We don’t want to see images of code here.

Comment: kindly tell me what information you required to help me..?

Comment: First of all, post your code as an snippet with Stack's text tools

Comment: Firebase doesn't run PHP code. You need a host that supports PHP. (Also, your login code is entirely insecure. Someone can just go directly to data.html.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display blade.php files using firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39522840/how-to-display-blade-php-files-using-firebase)